# How to get xy coordinates of child element from parent element in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, position

How to get xy coordinates of child element from parent element, and not the(body)? How to get x value from DIV B to DIV A, so when window resizes, the values stay true???

[image]

```
var startPos = $("#divB").position();
$("#divB").draggable({ 
     containment: 'parent',
     stop: function(event, ui) {
        var stopPos = $(this).position();
        $("#firstInput").val((stopPos.left - startPos.left));
     }
});
```

Is there a method to get this values directly and not from xy coordinates of whole screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the offset of a child element relative to its' parent use `position()`:

```
$("#child").position().left;
$("#child").position().top;
```

The caveat on this being that the parent must **NOT** be `position: static` for this to work. If the parent is static, jQuery will just return the `offset()` - which I assume is what is happening in your code.

`static` is the default for most block elements, so you'll need to set `position` to `fixed`, `absolute` or `relative` on the parent in your CSS.