# How to get coordinates of element from top of element to container?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the coordinates of the box on the image. The coordinates should be based on the image itself and not on the screen size. I am currently using `getBoundingClientRect()`. How do I retrieve the coordinates based on the image, the box is on, rather than the window size?

#### CODE that I've tried:

```
var rect = div[index].getBoundingClientRect();
```

I found this post on SO : [How to get xy coordinates of child element from parent element in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446179/how-to-get-xy-coordinates-of-child-element-from-parent-element-in-jquery) but it was 7 years ago...

Comment: Why would the answer from 7 years ago no longer apply today?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would use the difference between the elements position and its containers position. I've used [getBoundingClientRect and returned a new DomRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) like you were trying but be cautions as there is no support for Internet Expolorer, Edge or Safari at the moment.

```js
const getBoundingClientRect_RelativeToParent = element => {
  const domRect = element.getBoundingClientRect(),
    parentDomRect = element.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect()

  return new DOMRect(domRect.left - parentDomRect.left, domRect.top - parentDomRect.top, domRect.width, domRect.height)
}

console.log(getBoundingClientRect_RelativeToParent(document.querySelector(".child")))
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  background: green;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red
}

body {
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```